# FileUtil.copyMerge() in AWS S3

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-s3, hdfs

I have Loaded a `DataFrame` into `HDFS` as `text` format using below code. `finalDataFrame` is the `DataFrame`

```
finalDataFrame.repartition(1).rdd.saveAsTextFile(targetFile)
```

After executing the above code I found that a directory created with the file name I provided and under the directory a file created but not in text format. The file name is like **part-00000**.

I have resolved this in `HDFS` using below code.

```
val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), true, hadoopConfig, null)
```

Now I can get the text file in the mentioned path with given file name.

But when I am trying to do the same operation in S3 it is showing some exception

```
FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), true, hadoopConfig, null)

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:
s3a://globalhadoop/data, expected:
hdfs://*********.aws.*****.com:8050
```

It seems that S3 path is not supporting over here. Can anyone please assist how to do this.

Comment: _a file created but not in text format. File name is like part-00000_ - it is in a text format. Just check its content.

Comment: I want the file in .txt format and don't want any directory. Done this in HDFS. Need the same for S3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved the problem using below code.

```
def createOutputTextFile(srcPath: String, dstPath: String, s3BucketPath: String): Unit = {
    var fileSystem: FileSystem = null
    var conf: Configuration = null
    if (srcPath.toLowerCase().contains("s3a") || srcPath.toLowerCase().contains("s3n")) {
      conf = sc.hadoopConfiguration
      fileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(s3BucketPath), conf)
    } else {
      conf = new Configuration()
      fileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf)
    }
    FileUtil.copyMerge(fileSystem, new Path(srcPath), fileSystem, new Path(dstPath), true, conf, null)
  }
```

I have written the code for filesystem of S3 and HDFS and both are working fine.

Comment: This is over complex. create a path with new  Path(s3BucketPath), then go path.getFileSystem(sc.hadoopConfiguration), irrespective of what your destination path is. You'll get whatever FS you need

Answer (score 0):

You are passing in the hdfs filesystem as the destination FS in `FileUtil.copyMerge`. You need to get the real FS of the destination, which you can do by calling `Path.getFileSystem(Configuration)` on the destination path you have created.